# How to show the upcoming 3 months from the current date

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
        var month = (new Date()).getMonth();
        for (; month < monthNames.length; month++) {
        $('select').append('<option>' + monthNames[month] + '</option>');
        }
    });
```

How to show the upcoming 3 months from the current date as a dropdown using jquery and when the current or next month is completed I need to show respective upcoming 3 months as a dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very close, you just need to add a counter so that you only output 3 values, and when incrementing `month` you need to use modulo arithmetic so that you can wrap around the year when you get to December:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var month = ((new Date()).getMonth()+1)%12;
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++, month = (month + 1) % 12) {
    $('select').append('<option>' + monthNames[month] + '</option>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
</select>
```

Comment: @User863 it's not 100% clear from the question but I have modified...

Comment: Thanks, I hope this may help me

Answer (score 0):

Using [`toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

```js
var date = new Date()
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1, 1)
  $('select').append('<option>' + date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
    month: 'long'
  }) + '</option>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select></select>
```

Comment: You probably should have a note that some Android browsers don't support locales and options.